# Tensorflow indexing into 2d tensor with 1d tensor

Tags: tensorflow

I have a 2D tensor `A` with shape `[batch_size, D]` , and a 1D tensor `B` with shape `[batch_size]`.  Each element of `B` is a column index of `A`, for each row of `A`, eg. `B[i] in [0,D)`.

What is the best way in tensorflow to get the values `A[B]`

For example:

```
A = tf.constant([[0,1,2],
                 [3,4,5]])
B = tf.constant([2,1])
```

with desired output:

```
some_slice_func(A, B) -> [2,4]
```

There is another constraint.  In practice, `batch_size` is actually `None`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get it working using a linear index:

```
def vector_slice(A, B):
    """ Returns values of rows i of A at column B[i]

    where A is a 2D Tensor with shape [None, D] 
    and B is a 1D Tensor with shape [None] 
    with type int32 elements in [0,D)

    Example:
      A =[[1,2], B = [0,1], vector_slice(A,B) -> [1,4]
          [3,4]]
    """
    linear_index = (tf.shape(A)[1]
                   * tf.range(0,tf.shape(A)[0]))
    linear_A = tf.reshape(A, [-1])
    return tf.gather(linear_A, B + linear_index)
```

This feels slightly hacky though.

If anyone knows a better (as in clearer or faster) please also leave an answer! (I won't accept my own for a while)

Answer (score 1):

Code for what @Eugene Brevdo said:

```
def vector_slice(A, B):
    """ Returns values of rows i of A at column B[i]

    where A is a 2D Tensor with shape [None, D]
    and B is a 1D Tensor with shape [None]
    with type int32 elements in [0,D)

    Example:
      A =[[1,2], B = [0,1], vector_slice(A,B) -> [1,4]
          [3,4]]
    """
    B = tf.expand_dims(B, 1)
    range = tf.expand_dims(tf.range(tf.shape(B)[0]), 1)
    ind = tf.concat([range, B], 1)
    return tf.gather_nd(A, ind)
```

Answer (score 0):

the least hacky way is probably to build a proper 2d index by concatenating range(batch_size) and B, to get a batch_size x 2 matrix.  then pass this to tf.gather_nd.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to do:

```py
def tensor_slice(target_tensor, index_tensor):
    indices = tf.stack([tf.range(tf.shape(index_tensor)[0]), index_tensor], 1)
    return tf.gather_nd(target_tensor, indices)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use `tf.one_hot`, `tf.math.multiply` and `tf.reduce_sum` to solve it.

e.g.

```
def vector_slice (inputs, inds, axis = None):
    axis = axis if axis is not None else tf.rank(inds) - 1

    inds = tf.one_hot(inds, inputs.shape[axis])
    for i in tf.range(tf.rank(inputs) - tf.rank(inds)):
        inds = tf.expand_dims(inds, axis = -1)
    
    inds = tf.cast(inds, dtype = inputs.dtype)
    
    x = tf.multiply(inputs, inds)

    return tf.reduce_sum(x, axis = axis)
```