# Slicing a 2D tensor similar to numpy np.ix_

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have learned how to slice a tensor on one dimension [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64081367/slicing-a-tensor-with-a-tensor-of-indices-and-tf-gather).

I have learned how to slice a 2D tensor giving a 1D tensor of specific values [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38492608/tensorflow-indexing-into-2d-tensor-with-1d-tensor).

Both use `tf.gather()` but I'm pretty sure I need `tf.gather_nd()` though I'm obviously using it wrong.

In numpy, I have a 5x5 2D array, and I can slice a 2x2 array by using `np.ix_()` with row and column indices (I always need the same indices for rows and columns, resulting in a squared matrix):

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[2,1,6,7,8],[3,6,1,9,10],[4,7,9,1,11],[5,8,10,11,1]])

a
```

> ```
> array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
>       [ 2,  1,  6,  7,  8],
>       [ 3,  6,  1,  9, 10],
>       [ 4,  7,  9,  1, 11],
>       [ 5,  8, 10, 11,  1]])
> ```

```py
a[np.ix_([1,3], [1,3])]
```

> ```
> array([[1, 7],
>       [7, 1]])
> ```

Reading over the [`tf.gather_nd()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd) docs I assumed this is the way to do it in TF, but I'm using it wrong:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant([[1,2,3,4,5],[2,1,6,7,8],[3,6,1,9,10],[4,7,9,1,11],[5,8,10,11,1]])

tf.gather_nd(a, [[1,3], [1,3]])
```

> ```
> <tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([7, 7])>
> ```

I would have to do something like:

```py
tf.gather_nd(a, [[[1,1], [1,3]],[[3,1],[3,3]]])
```

> ```
> <tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 2), dtype=int32, numpy=
> array([[1, 7],
>       [7, 1]])>
> ```

Which leads me down another rabbit hole I'm not keen on. My indices vector is a lot longer of course.

My indices, BTW, are 1D integer tensors themselves. So bottom-line I want to slice `a` with the same indices for rows and columns as I do with `np._ix()`, and my indices are something like:

```py
idx = tf.constant([1, 3])

# tf.gather_nd(a, indices = "something with idx")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To slice a nxn 2D array with a 1D tensor of length d that results in a dxd 2D array with the specified indices, it can be done by using `tf.repeat`, `tf.tile` and then `tf.stack`:

```
n = 5
a = tf.constant(np.arange(n * n).reshape(n, n)) # 2D nxn array
idx = [1,2,4] # 1D tensor with length d
d = tf.shape(idx)[0]
ix_ = tf.reshape(tf.stack([tf.repeat(idx,d),tf.tile(idx,[d])],1),[d,d,2])
target = tf.gather_nd(a,ix_) # 2D dxd array
print(a)
print(target)
```

Expected outputs:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8  9]
 [10 11 12 13 14]
 [15 16 17 18 19]
 [20 21 22 23 24]], shape=(5, 5), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor(
[[ 6  7  9]
 [11 12 14]
 [21 22 24]], shape=(3, 3), dtype=int64)
```

Comment: How does your `ix_` change if I have two different `idx` lists, eg `idx1=[1,2,3]` and `idx2=[1,2]`, for each dimension of the 2D array (yielding an asymmetric `target`)?

Comment: Similarly to `a[np.ix_([1,2,3], [1,2])]`.